# How do I fix the 3D screen in Minecraft Story Mode?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

Every time I try to open up Minecraft Story Mode it displays everything as 3D. If you have any information on how to fix this issue, please share.

Comment: Can you include screenshots?

Comment: Although you haven't posted any screenshots, I'm assuming you're talking about stereoscopic/anaglyph 3D. If so, there should be an option either in-game, or in your video driver options, to turn it off.